# Crypto++ output data length

Tags: aes, crypto++

I am trying to use AES encryption from Crypto++ libary:

```
CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption e;
```

I have a binary data block that I need to encrypt. The class seems to provide a method called `ProcessData` for this purpose:

```
virtual void ProcessData(byte *outString, const byte *inString, size_t length);
```

Looks like the last parameter is the size of the input data. What is not clear is why the method does not return me the size of the encrypted data. Is it assumed that the size of output data block is exactly the same as the length of input data block? Is this valid even if the size of input data is just one byte? Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Why the down vote? Is it not a legit question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> virtual void ProcessData(byte *outString, const byte *inString, size_t length);
> ```
>
> Looks like the last parameter is the size of the input data. What is not clear is why the method does not return me the size of the encrypted data...

`ProcessData` is the workhorse of all block ciphers (but not stream ciphers or other types of objects). Also see the Crypto++ manual and [cryptlib.h File Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/cryptlib_8h.html). `cryptlib.h` is described as *"Abstract base classes that provide a uniform interface to this library"*.

`ProcessData` operates on block-sized lengths of data. So `INSIZE` is equal to `OUTSIZE` is equal to `BLOCKSIZE`. Note that there is no `INSIZE` or `OUTSIZE` - I used them for discussion. Each block cipher will provide a constant for `BLOCKSIZE`. There will be a `AES::BLOCKSIZE`, `DES_EDE::BLOCKSIZE`, etc.

Typically you *do not* use `ProcessData` directly. You can use it directly, but you will be responsible for all the associated details (more on the details below).

Typically you use a `StreamTransformationFilter`, but its not readily apparent why. `StreamTransformationFilter` provides input buffering, output buffering, and padding as required. Its briefly discussed at [Init-Update-Final](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Init-Update-Final) on the wiki.

Here's how it looks in practice from the [CBC mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_mode) example on the Crypto++ wiki:

```
try
{
    cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

    CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), iv );

    // The StreamTransformationFilter adds padding
    //  as required. ECB and CBC Mode must be padded
    //  to the block size of the cipher.
    StringSource ss( plain, true, 
        new StreamTransformationFilter( e,
            new StringSink( cipher )
        ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
    ); // StringSource
}
catch( const CryptoPP::Exception& e )
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

In the above, `CBC_mode` and `StreamTransformationFilter` work together to give you desired results. `CBC_mode` calls `ProcessData` and handles the cipher chaining details. `StreamTransformationFilter` feeds the plain text in its preferred size. If there's not enough plain text, then `StreamTransformationFilter` buffers it on input. If there's no output buffer, then `StreamTransformationFilter` buffers cipher text, too.

`StreamTransformationFilter` will also apply padding as required. There's a default padding, but you can override it. `StreamTransformationFilter` knows what padding to apply because it asks the mode (`CBC_mode`) if the padding is required and what the padding should be.

---

> ... Is it assumed that the size of output data block is exactly the same as the length of input data block? Is this valid even if the size of input data is just one byte?

This is where the `StreamTransformationFilter` fits into the equation.

Be sure to check out [Init-Update-Final](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Init-Update-Final) on the wiki. It should provide the glue for you if you are used to Java or OpenSSL programming. It should help "make it click" for you.