# AES/CFB encryption with Crypto++ not working

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I have a simple console program that should encrypt files with AES CFB algorithm from Crypto++ library. For some reason it is not working. Encoding part:

```
byte data[16] = { 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44 };

byte result[16] = { 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44 };

//Sample key
byte key[16] = { 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
                 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44 };

//Generate random Initialization Vector
byte iv[16];
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE /*16*/);

//Through VisualStudio debug/watch functionality I have found out that Crypto++ randomizer works properly so at this point "iv" contains random values

CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption tmp(key, 16, iv, 1);
tmp.ProcessData(data, result, 16);
```

The problem is that after last line of code in this part (tmp.ProcessData(data, result, 16);) nothing in `result` changes.
I was guided by this official tutorial:
https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: `CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption(key, 16, iv, 1) tmp;` is odd syntax. Did you mean `CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption tmp(key, 16, iv, 1);`?

Comment: Try making `data` const and see what errors you get...

Comment: @MikeVine. yes, sorry I just copy pasted it from `CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption(key, 16, iv, 1).ProcessData (data, result, 16);` and added `tmp` between. But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MikeVine. About `const data` Thanks I'll try.

Comment: @MikeVine. Making `const byte data[16]` doesn't change anything. I suppose you suggested `const byte result[16]`? If yes then it also doesn't change anything. Also I tried `tmp.ProcessData((const byte*)data, (const byte*)result, 16);`

Comment: I can't find the explicit docs for CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption but other uses of [ProcessData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685190/crypto-output-data-length) suggest the out-string (e.g. `result`) is the _first_ parameter.

Comment: @MikeVine. Did you mean   `cfbEncryption.ProcessData((byte*)plainText,(byte*)plainText, messageLen);`?

Comment: No the 5th line in the question: `virtual void ProcessData(byte *outString, const byte *inString, size_t length);`

Comment: @MikeVine. Thanks a lot! That solved my problem. You can make it as answer.