# Encryption with Crypto++/AES CFB not working

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I have a simple console program that should encrypt files with AES CFB algorithm from Crypto++ library. For some reason it is not working. Encoding part:

```
byte data[16] = { 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
                  0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44 };

byte result[16] = { 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                    0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                    0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
                    0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44 };

//Sample key
byte key[16] = { 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44,
                 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
                 0x88, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44 };

//Generate random Initialization Vector
byte iv[16];
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE /*16*/);

//Through VisualStudio debug/watch functionality I have found out that
//Crypto++ randomizer works properly so at this point "iv" contains random values

CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption tmp(key, 16, iv, 1);
tmp.ProcessData(data, result, 16);
```

The problem is that when this code completes `result` is supposed to be filled with cyphertext but it just remains filled with `px88` and `0x44`. 
I was guided by this official tutorial: https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES Encryption with Crypto++ not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352882/aes-encryption-with-crypto-not-working)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... How is this different than the cited duplicate?

Comment: @jww. They have no difference. I did it because I had no answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessData` is `outstring`, then `instring` then length. You've switched the input and output parameters `data` & `result` (most API's would put output parameters last in their method declarations, so this could explain the mistake).